# understanding decision table in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was just going through the code of Jbox and cam across the following snippet of code:

```
// Internal functions, used to easily get values
    this._getOpp = function(opp) { 
      return {left: 'right', 
      right: 'left', 
      top: 'bottom', 
      bottom: 'top',
      x: 'y', 
      y: 'x'}[opp]; 
    };
```

He seems to be interchanging values, fair enough, what is the [opp] in the end doing though ? that's my question, and example of where the _getOpp function gets used is **[HERE](https://github.com/StephanWagner/jBox/blob/master/Source/jBox.js#L548)**. I have never seen something like this in JavaScript, can anybody explain ?

Comment: its like a `switch`, it will return a value according to `opp`

Comment: @Hacketo , Wow , in what way ? a little demo might be helpful .

Comment: You can think of it as a state machine, with the keys representing the current state and the values the new state.

Comment: ~ `function getOpp(opp) {
  switch(opp) {
    case 'left': return 'right';
    case 'right': return 'left';
    //.... 
    default: return undefined;
  }
}`

Comment: BTW This approach is OK for internal stuff but not recommended for public methods. Newly created object will inherit all Object.prototype members. For example `_getOpp('hasOwnProperty')`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko would the object not be garbage collected as soon as the method is returned anyway?? (I'm not argueeing your point, just wondering if the newly created object would amost immediatly be cleaned up)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thanks ! will keep that in mind !

Comment: @atmd I guess it would. It definitely should not survive the function call. To reuse object one can do `this._getOpp = (function(){var lookup = {/*...*/}; return function(opp){return lookup[opp];};}())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a technique that I know as a decision table ([a wrote a blog post about them a while ago](http://atmd.co.uk/javascript-decision-tables/)), but other might call it by different names.

It uses the square bracket notation in the same way you'd reference the index of an array:

```
var arr = [0, 2, 3];
return arr[1]; // return the second value in the array
```

Because object properties are `key`/`value` pairs it works like this:

```
  return {
    left: 'right', 
    right: 'left', 
    top: 'bottom', 
    bottom: 'top',
    x: 'y', 
    y: 'x'
  }[opp]
```

It will actually return the string `value`, to the `key` `opp`.

i.e. if `opp` is 'right', it will return 'left'.

**n.b.** the [wiki page on decision tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table) is also worth a read

Answer (score 1):

It creates an `object` with values first, then return a specific `attr` in the object whose key is the given `opp`. And if no such key is founded, `undefined` is returned.

You can see them as :

```
var states= {
    left: 'right', 
    right: 'left', 
    top: 'bottom', 
    bottom: 'top',
    x: 'y', 
    y: 'x'
};
return settings[opp];
```

The snippet shows how it would act.

```js
var getOpp = function(opp) { 
      return {left: 'right', 
      right: 'left', 
      top: 'bottom', 
      bottom: 'top',
      x: 'y', 
      y: 'x'}[opp]; 
};

console.log(getOpp('right'));
console.log(getOpp('oops'));
```